# is it possible to lock a user account (g suite) programmatically using google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

also is it possible to do that after a certain log-in attempts?

I'm trying to create a script that locks the user's account after a certain number of failed login attempts.

I tried to check if any functions can be used to access the account setting, or how many times this user failed to login, but I got nothing so far.

Gmail Service allows scripts to send email and access a user's Gmail account.
With only these Classes

Name            Brief description

1. GmailApp     : Provides access to Gmail threads, messages, and labels.
2. GmailAttachment   : An attachment from Gmail.
3. GmailDraft        : A user-created draft message in a user's Gmail account.
4. GmailLabel        :  A user-created label in a user's Gmail account.
5. GmailMessage       : A message in a user's Gmail account.
6. GmailThread         : A thread in a user's Gmail account.

also as far as I know the lock service allows scripts to prevents concurrent access to sections of code(e.g multiple users or processes modifying a shared resource to prevent collisions) but not locking an account .

any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it's not possible. Definitely not possible via the Gmail API. Your problem is getting the failed logins in real time, after that the reset is easy enough.

Have a look at the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) for the functions you need: in particular the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login) for failed logins & the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) for managing user accounts.

Comment: alright ,thank you,what you said is true . i was just wondering if it can be done in scripts ,but seems like there's no workaround to get the attempts in real time.